# JQuery - Sort <p> using two data, when one is equal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiples P elements inside multiples divs, and I can sort then using attr data-sort

```
<p class="7389" data-sort="4" data-maquina="1" style="color: rgb(65, 151, 244); font-size: 12px;"> Compra e Venda - R-4-7389 -   --&gt; DIG11</p>

<p class="7389" data-sort="4" data-maquina="2" style="color: rgb(65, 151, 244); font-size: 12px;"> Compra e Venda - R-4-7389 -   --&gt; DIG11</p>
```

But sometimes, the data-sort is same of the previous and the next element, and I need to keep the (data-maquina = 1) always first then (data-maquina = 2).

How I can sort the P elements using two data parameters?

I have this code to compare the data sort and it is working:

```
function sort_li(a, b) {
    if ($(b).data('sort') == $(a).data('sort')){
        console.log("??????");
    } else {
        return ($(b).data('sort')) < ($(a).data('sort')) ? 1 : -1;      
    }
}


for (i = 0; i < matriculasunicas.length; ++i) {
    var iddamatricula = '#'+matriculasunicas[i];
    $(iddamatricula + "> p").sort(sort_li).appendTo(iddamatricula); // append again to the list 
}
```

What I use on the If statement?
I hope be clearly.
On the (????)! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just check other data:

```
function sort_li(a, b){
    if($(b).data('sort') == $(a).data('sort')){
        return ($(b).data('maquina')) < ($(a).data('maquina')) ? 1 : -1;
    }else{
        return ($(b).data('sort')) < ($(a).data('sort')) ? 1 : -1;      
    }
}
```